Proving the Equality of Infinite Cardinal Products and Powers
Theorem: Let $\Xi$ be an infinite set, $\{\kappa_i\}_{i \in \Xi}$ be a family of cardinal numbers, and $\lambda$ be a cardinal number. Then:
$\prod_{i \in \Xi} \kappa_i^{\lambda} = \left(\prod_{i \in \Xi} \kappa_i\right)^{\lambda}$
Proof:
We begin by recalling the definition of the infinite product of sets:
Definition: For a family of sets $\{K_i\}_{i \in \Xi}$,
$\prod_{i \in \Xi} K_i := \left\{\phi \in \left(\bigcup_{i \in \Xi} K_i\right)^{\Xi} \mid \forall i \in \Xi: \phi(i) \in K_i\right\}$
Now, let's proceed with the proof:

Let $K_i$ be sets with $|K_i| = \kappa_i$ for all $i \in \Xi$. Define:
$H := \prod_{i \in \Xi} K_i^{\lambda} = \left\{\phi \in \left(\bigcup_{i \in \Xi} K_i^{\lambda}\right)^{\Xi} \mid \forall i \in \Xi: \phi(i) \in K_i^{\lambda}\right\}$
Then, by definition of cardinal arithmetic:
$\prod_{i \in \Xi} \kappa_i^{\lambda} = |H|$

Similarly, let:
$K := \prod_{i \in \Xi} K_i = \left\{\phi \in \left(\bigcup_{i \in \Xi} K_i\right)^{\Xi} \mid \forall i \in \Xi: \phi(i) \in K_i\right\}$.
Then:
$\left(\prod_{i \in \Xi} \kappa_i\right)^{\lambda} = |K|^{\lambda} = |K^{\lambda}|$

To prove the equality, we will establish a bijection $G: K^{\lambda} \rightarrow H$.

For any $g \in K^{\lambda}$, define $G(g): \Xi \rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in \Xi} K_i^{\lambda}$ as follows:
For each $i \in \Xi$, $G(g)(i): \lambda \rightarrow K_i$ is given by:
$G(g)(i)(\eta) := g(\eta)(i) \quad \forall \eta \in \lambda$

To prove injectivity, suppose $G(g_1) = G(g_2)$ for $g_1, g_2 \in K^{\lambda}$.
Then for all $i \in \Xi$ and $\eta \in \lambda$:
$G(g_1)(i)(\eta) = G(g_2)(i)(\eta) \implies g_1(\eta)(i) = g_2(\eta)(i)$.
This implies $g_1 = g_2$, proving injectivity.

To prove surjectivity, let $\phi \in H$. Define $g: \lambda \rightarrow K$ as follows:
For each $\eta \in \lambda$, let $g(\eta): \Xi \rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in \Xi} K_i$ be given by:
$g(\eta)(i) := \phi(i)(\eta) \quad \forall i \in \Xi$.
Note that $g(\eta) \in K$ for all $\eta \in \lambda$, so $g \in K^{\lambda}$.
Moreover, for all $i \in \Xi$ and $\eta \in \lambda$:
$G(g)(i)(\eta) = g(\eta)(i) = \phi(i)(\eta)$.
Therefore, $G(g) = \phi$, proving surjectivity.

We have shown that $G$ is a bijection between $K^{\lambda}$ and $H$.
Thus, $|K^{\lambda}| = |H|$, which implies:
$\left(\prod_{i \in \Xi} \kappa_i\right)^{\lambda} = \prod_{i \in \Xi} \kappa_i^{\lambda}$


I'm concerned about the rigor of the bijection construction in this proof. Specifically, when defining $G: K^{\lambda} \rightarrow H$, how can we ensure that the mapping $G(g)(i)(\eta) := g(\eta)(i)$ is well-defined and truly bijective? In simpler cases, such as proving $(Y \times Z)^X \cong Y^X \times Z^X$, we need to carefully construct the bijection using projection functions:
$f: (Y \times Z)^X \rightarrow Y^X \times Z^X$
$\phi \mapsto f(\phi) := (h_Y, h_Z)$
where $h_Y(x) = \pi_Y(\phi(x))$ and $h_Z(x) = \pi_Z(\phi(x))$ for all $x \in X$, with $\pi_Y$ and $\pi_Z$ being the projection functions from $Y \times Z$ to $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.
Is our construction of $G$ in the infinite case as rigorous? Are there any potential pitfalls or oversights in this approach that we should address? How can we make the proof more robust and explicit in its construction of $G$?

@Ulli: You're right, I was thinking about sums. My bad!

Here is a proof:
If you don't mind, I'll write $I$ instead of $\Xi$,
since we have to swap between the index set and $\lambda$.
Thus, it might be more convenient to have the same letter for the index set and the indices.
For each $i \in I, \alpha < \lambda$ define $\kappa_{i, \alpha} = \kappa_i$.
We have
$\bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} (\{\alpha\} \times I) = \lambda \times I =
 \bigcup_{i \in I} (\lambda \times \{i\})$,
where both unions are disjoint unions. Hence
$$(\prod_{i \in I} \kappa_i)^\lambda = 
  \prod_{\alpha < \lambda} (\prod_{i \in I} \kappa_{i, \alpha}) = 
  \prod_{(\alpha, i) \in \lambda \times I} \kappa_{i, \alpha} =
  \prod_{i \in I} (\prod_{\alpha < \lambda} \kappa_{i, \alpha}) =
  \prod_{i \in I} (\kappa_i^\lambda)
$$
by associativity of cardinal products.

Thank you. This elegant proof is remarkable.
